# How can I get php to respond to get request?

Tags: php, curl

As a preface I would like to say that I am very new to php AND to stack overflow so this is a very beginner question.

For some context: I am doing an ubuntu autoinstall and am following the following forum post for some extra settings I'm trying to do: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290624/fetch-autoinstall-based-on-mac

So the installer does a curl command which if understand correctly sends a GET request to the http server which will run some php code and finally return an edited file (is what is supposed to happen). How can i get a php environment up and running to do just this?

I have the apache http server running which I can use to get files with curl, I just need to know how to "catch" the get request and send back an edited file.

Comment: The problem might not be a php problem. Is the remote server up and running? Is the apache service running? Is the port open both on the server and on the network gateway?  Are you using port 80, 443, or a different one? Is the request encrypted? If the request is encrypted, is the ssl set up on the server? You might check along those lines to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

just create a PHP file in your webserver root directory then send your request to http://yourserver/your_php_file.php
Your webserver will call the file your_php_file.php and this file will have to send back an edited file ;)

Comment: could you give an example of how this php file looks like so it sends back the edited file as response?

Answer (score 1):

Try with a simple index.php file and navigate to it via the URL. The index.php file can be just this for starter:

```
<?php 

var_dump($_GET);
```

and after you see what is $_GET (and I recommend read about it) you will figure out what to do next :)